# command not found exception when accessing remote machine VIA ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, rhel, login

we have strange behavior when I access to some remote machine with ssh

all machines are `rhel 7.2` version

this is what we got

```
ssh server142
Last login: Thu May 27 09:44:13 2021 from  server_ER




-bash: server: command not found
-bash: stratumweight: command not found
-bash: driftfile: command not found
-bash: $'rtcsync\r': command not found
-bash: makestep: command not found
-bash: bindcmdaddress: command not found
-bash: bindcmdaddress: command not found
-bash: keyfile: command not found
-bash: commandkey: command not found
-bash: $'generatecommandkey\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'noclientlog\r': command not found
-bash: logchange: command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: logdir: command not found
```

so we checked the `$PATH` on the bad server and compare it to other good server but both $PATH output are the same output

example

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

we also compared the `bashrc` between machines the good and the bad and also no differences

any hint what could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: It might be deeper in the initialization files -- compare the files in /etc/profile.d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the file `/etc/bash_completion.d/chrony.conf`

so we moved this file as

```
 mv /etc/bash_completion.d/chrony.conf /var/tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\r` in some of the messages is a strong hint that you have Windows line endings in a file.

Comment: ... perhaps a [chrony.conf](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/doc/3.5/chrony.conf.html) file specifically

Comment: I performed  dos2unix bashrc , but still with the same problem

Comment: I performed dos2unix  /etc/chrony.conf
, but still with the same problem

Comment: I checked but no diff between other good machines